# Can't unpublish my chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

All of a sudden I am unable to unpublish my Chrome extensions from the Developer Dashboard. If I click the Unpublish link nothing happens. If I open the Chrome console I can see that when I click the Unpublish link the following is shown in the console:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`

and it references the following:

`crxgallery_csi.js:232`

Has anyone else had this problem? I tried a different browser and it still will not unpublish. I tried another of my extensions and it does the same thing.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using the Chrome Web Store. The correct place to post such questions is the Chromium-apps Google Group (https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-apps).